# BufferedReader - Does it take in the entire document?

Tags: java, performance, memory, bufferedreader

I'm currently working with BufferedReader, and was wondering, When we create a new BufferedReader with an InputStreamReader (i.e new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(FileInputStream)) as the parameter for it, does that mean the BufferedReader is already reading in the entire bytes of a file from the FileInputStream via InputStreamReader? Or is it only reading the necessary bytes as it's controlled to (i.e readLine()).

Below is an example of my code:

```
File inputFile = new File("C:\\foo\\foo.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String line = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: No. The size of buffer of `BufferedReader` is 8192 bytes.

Comment: Ah, so the memory usage of BufferedReader will always be on a constant 8192 bytes?

Comment: Yes, unless you change the buffer size.